# For loop iterating not executed with condition set inside

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, iteration

I have a simple python loop that iterate over a 2D list which has 1000 sublist inside. Each sublist will contain 3 string values. I only want to change the sublists which are after the 365th sublist. I also have a very trivial condition which will decide if an operation will be applied to the element. My minimum code is as follows:

```
def change_list(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if i < 365:
            pass
        else:
            arr[i][1] = str(int(arr[i][1]) * 2)
```

When apply this function in `main` I'll simply invoke this function as: `change_list(parsed_lines)`. For parsed lines, I'll just give a simple example:

```
parsed_lines = [["afkj","12","234"]] * 1000
```

My function will do the "multiply by 2" operation on all sublists, which is an unexpected behavior. I've tried not using conditions, but results in the same behavior.

```
for i in range(365, len(arr)):
    arr[i][1] = str(int(arr[i][1]) * 2)
```

Then I tried the other way to iterate my arr as:

```
for line in arr:
    if arr.index(line) < 365:
        print("I'm less than 365")
    else:
        line[1] = str(int(line[1]) * 2)
```

but this iteration will never execute the block under `else`. I am very confused by this, hope someone can help.

**Update:**

The expected behavior should be:

1. For `arr[0: 365]`, the sublist will stay the same as: `[["afkj","12","234"]]`
2. For `arr[365:]`, the sublist will be: `[["afkj","24","234"]]`

Comment: You are iterating over a *range*, which returns *integers* that you use to index into your *list*. Your list is only `len(arr) == 5`, so `i` is never not `i < 365`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I just gave portion of my data, the entire list has 1000 items.

Comment: you code is good just mixed up arr and parsed_lines I think

Comment: @LingboTang Well, then you need to provide a *reproducible example of the problem*. Furthermore, you need to be less vague about what you are expecting as output, and what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just multiply parsed_lines 100 times or so

Comment: @Serge And? What happens? More importantly, what is *expected to happen*?

Comment: he say for first snippet all elements are duplicated and none for second snippet. ( Just a sec ago he broke the list example i think to runtime error )

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I changed my description and has given the example you want.

Comment: @Serge I don't think so, I extracted this function out of my complicated `main`, and only gave the example in this question as parameter, I still got the unexpected result.

Comment: @LingboTang The example you provided *fails because of the way you are creating your example list*. `[[1,2,3]]*100` creates a list of lists of length 100 where each sublist *is the same list*. So changes will be reflected at every element. I don't think that is the root of your issue, though

Comment: In other words, if you are actually generating your list like `parsed_lines = [["afkj","12","234"]] * 1000` that, then *dont do that*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's what I'm thinking too because python hide some lower level reference to programmers.

Comment: was bad advice, direct multiply fails  but map(list, [("afkj","12","234")] * 1000) should work

Comment: @Serge This is a neat solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem, as described, is not in the program, but in the test set. `parsed_lines = [["afkj","12","234"]] * 1000` creates a list of 1000 references to the same list `["afkj","12","234"]`. When it is modified through any of those references (say, above 365), it is seen as modified through any of those references (even below 365). In other words, `parsed_lines[0][0]='foo'` makes all fisrt elements in all sublists `'foo'`.

Comment: Is there a way that I can check the reference in python as C or C++?

Comment: You can use function `id()`, but in this case it is obvious. That's how operator `*` works on lists.

Comment: I would also like to know how to self-concatenate the list by different reference. `*` seems simple, but it's not doing the job.

Comment: Please read all comments to your post. They suggest a solution.

Comment: Yes, I see that. Thanks